# How can I convince players who "want a new challenge" to stay?

Tags: football-manager-2013, football-manager-2014

After 9 seasons with a team I got a player that "*wants a new challenge*".
Of course, he asked to put him on transfer, so I had to sell him.

Now there are other 2 players who want to leave too and this is really frustrating.

Is there a solution to this issue? How can I convince them to stay?

I play FM 2013 on Android device and FM 2014 on PC.

Comment: Which game are you talking about?  2013 or 2014?  You only need one tag.

Comment: @Frank booth of them: i play with FM2013 on Android device, and FM2014 on PC. I'll edit my question then.

Comment: Does this new challenge thing happen with both?  I haven't played either, I'm just trying to narrow down where your question is coming from.

Comment: @Frank first it happened on PC, then in Android device. The 2 games are not linked (also i manage 2 different team). I was only curious to figure out if i can fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an entire season spent in the game, I found the "solution" by myself:

- I offered to the first player (the mercenary) a new contract, of course with a better pay, and this solved the issue;
- I offered to the second one a new contract, also with more pay than the first one; he didn't accepted the offer, so I sold him with discount (because this was his last year).

This was my way of acting. However, I wonder if I send the player on loan, he could possibly change his mind. Luckily I don't have another mutinous player, so feel free to improve my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to keep my Defensive Midfielder that was very unhappy by sending him on loan (I also got good amount of money for this).  When he came back, he no longer wanted to leave the club.